# Getting an error in a mongo node condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is wrong with this condition?

```
  var conditions = {
    $and: [
        {username: req.body.globalUserName},
        $or: [
            {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()},
            {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}
        ]
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
            $or: [
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

This is for a fineOneAndUpdate query. What is wrong with my condition code? Thanks so much! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each condition should be an object.

The `and` operator is an array, but you encounter it as an object.

```
var conditions = {
    $and: [
        {username: req.body.globalUserName},
        {$or: [
            {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()},
            {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}
        ]}
    ]
}
```